# Showing a facebook page feed on IOS app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, json, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

I want to show a facebook feed of a page into my IOS app. Now I looked at a PHP example and that is doing the following.

```
$profile_id = "111111111111111231";

//App Info, needed for Auth
$app_id = "12312424123214123124123";
$app_secret = "12312421415123124123";

//Retrieve auth token
$authToken = fetchUrl("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?type=client_cred&client_id={$app_id}&client_secret={$app_secret}");

$json_object = fetchUrl("https://graph.facebook.com/{$profile_id}/feed?{$authToken}");
//echo "https://graph.facebook.com/{$profile_id}/feed?{$authToken}";
```

Offcourse I've changed the codes to fake ones. But when I go through the steps in the browser with the correct codes. I get my feed in JSON.

My question is now, is it OK to just translate this PHP to Objective-c code and parse the JSON? Or are there things that I need to keep in mind?

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

JSON answer from facebook for PHP or Objective-c is the same BUT the answer is paged.

I mean, you get the first results that stays on a page and then a link to the next page, 
so the parser should follow the next links till the end of results (or till you like).

To check the answer you can use Graph API Explorer (me/feed ) or Objective-c [facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/feed" andDelegate:self];

You will find something like this

> "paging": {
>       "previous": "https://graph.facebook.com/100001050796104/feed?limit=25&since=1361206612", 
>       "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/100001050796104/feed?limit=25&until=1361193119"
>     }

So if you use JSON and parser you must implement a "follower" OR
you just use e UIWEBView and let the user to go through the links.

Hope this help